# AWS Cognito: Hosted UI how to customize the style of the Forgot Password in CSS Templete

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using **Hosted UI** of **AWS Cognito** for the authentication in the application. I want to change the font size and add the left margin on the headings **Forgot the Password** and **Enter your Email below and we will send a message to reset your password** as shown in the picture.

[image]

AWS Cognito's Hosted UI provides the CSS template to style the page. How could I change its style in **AWS Cognito** Hosted UI CSS template.css? If I try to add a function out of the mentioned classes in the CSS template then it will throw an exception and doesn't upload the CSS template.

Kindly guide me on this problem. Thanks

Comment: You can't. The options for customizing the hosted UI are extremely limited.